# Java resize image from an URL?

Tags: java

I want to resize the an image from an URL to 50x50 px.

This is how i load the image:

```
jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(new URL("http://url.com/picture.jpg")));
```

How can i make picture.jpg 50x50px ?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
public BufferedImage resize(final URL url, final Dimension size) throws IOException{
    final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);
    final BufferedImage resized = new BufferedImage(size.width, size.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    final Graphics2D g = resized.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, size.width, size.height, null);
    g.dispose();
    return resized;
}
```

Usage:

```
final BufferedImage image = resize(new URL("http://url.com/picture.jpg"), new Dimension(50, 50));
```

Answer (score 3):

- `ImageIcon` has a [`getImage()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#getImage%28%29) method, returning an `Image`.
- `Image` has a [`getScaledInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance%28int,%20int,%20int%29) method, returning a scaled `Image`.
- `ImageIcon` has a [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon%28java.awt.Image%29) taking an `Image` as argument.

I'll let you assemble the 3-pieces puzzle.